# Callbacks of cocoon gem in form construction action view update

Tags: javascript, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-5, cocoon-gem

When creating a form using a cocoon gem, when inserting a new cocoon, I can detect an action by calling the "cocoon: after insert" callback.

And I use this to replace the element of my id to make use of another javascript function to calculate the percentage in the other field, entered by the user.

But when I reopen the form using the update action, the cocoons are redefined. And this does not cause the callback "cocoon: after insert". to reset the id's, how it works when inserting one by one

I wanted to know if there is a way to capture the callbacks when returning the form for editing. So I can detect this and redraw the new ID again

I use this code in "form.html.erb" to replace the id when it creates new instances of the cocoon

```
var i = 0;
$(document).on('cocoon:after-insert', function (e) {
    i++;
    var id_drop_down_product = 'id_drop_down_product' + i;
    $(this).find("#id_drop_down_product").attr('id', id_drop_down_product);
});
```

I thought it would work, in building the form for editing

---

Here is my code that calls the cocoons, where everything is working too

```
<div class="form-group">
  <%= form.fields_for :pedido_produtos do |builder| %>
    <% render partial: "shared/pedido_produto_fields", locals: {f: builder} %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_association('Produto', form, :pedido_produtos, class: "btn btn-outline-success") %>
</div>


<div class="nested-fields">
  <div class="order_product">
    <div class="form-group col-md-12">
      <%= f.collection_select(:product_id, Product.all, :id, :nome, {:prompt => "Selecione um Product"}, {:class => 'form-control', onchange: "searchProduct($(this).val(),this.id);", id: "dropselectProduct", :required => true}) %>
      <%= f.text_field :quantity, class: "form-control", id: "quantityproducty", :required => true, onchange: "update_discount($(this).val(),this.id);" %>
      <%= f.text_field(:porcent, class: "form-control", id: "porcent", readonly: true) %>
    </div>
    <%= link_to_remove_association('Del.', f, class: "btn btn-outline-danger") %>
  </div>
</div>
```

in the view, I have a field, to get the value of the product and the value of the percentage field, (which was selected by the user) and calculate the percentage of the new value of the product.

but in this view, you can insert multiple products, and perform this action.

Picture view example:
https://ibb.co/s3Z43yk

Comment: Can you show the view code of the nested items? Please bear in mind that if you have repeating html id's in a form, only the first id will be actually saved. Could you not more easily use a class `.drop_down_product` instead? Why do you need an id?

Comment: I edited my question, I thank you if you can help me

Comment: Thank you for the elaboration. However, could you still explain _why_ you think you need the id? Because in most cases we can avoid the need? One cannot attach a handler to a unique id anyway, so I am a bit confused.